# How to implement multiple languages without abusing the Template system?

Tags: internationalization, meteor

I converted [our Meteor site](http://q42.com) to support two languages, Dutch and English. To do this I made two folders for our templates (en and nl) and hooked everything up to our templating system so the router serves things correctly depending on which site you're on. The [main body template](https://github.com/Q42/q42.nl/blob/master/client/main.js) is dynamic:

```
Template.body.content = function() {
  var lang = Session.get("lang") == "en" ? "en_" : "";
  var page = Session.get("page") || "home";

  // if the template for the current language doesn't exist,
  // fall back to Dutch version or show a 404
  var template = Template[lang + page] || Template[page] || Template[lang + "error404"];

  return template();
}
```

Everything works pretty well except that I have to write the following to expose a template value to both languages:

```
Template.en_foo.bar = Template.foo.bar = function() {}
```

For an example of this code as used in production, see [our client-side blog code](https://github.com/Q42/q42.nl/blob/master/client/blog.js).

What's an elegant way to avoid this approach while still accomplishing the goal of a multilingual site?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

- make a custom subscription and pass the language argument to a custom publish
- the custom publish function returns only the selected language (optionally you can provide fallbacks if content is unavailable)
- use just one template for all languages, filled with the right language from the subscription
- use i18n package for the UI strings

Answer (score 0):

Multi-languages applications is on the [Meteor roadmap](https://trello.com/card/i18n/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/38) but it's planned in a long time...

Meanwhile you can use this [atmosphere package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/simple-i18n).

Comment: This package is for internationalizing strings in a user interface, not for setting up multiple languages for the content of a site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend heavily against keeping translated versions of your templates around. Unless your site is *tiny*. It might not seem so bad at first because you just copy them and translate the contents. But from then on you'll have to maintain both versions on any change, test both. And then somebody will suggest adding that third language and boom, triple damage to your brain.

We're using [meteor-messageformat](http://messageformat.meteor.com/) for translations. It comes with an interface that allows creating translations without having to look at template code. Anybody can translate.